# HTML image link has a small blue tic mark below it

Tags: html, css

I have an a tag with an image inside of it and for some reason the a tag looks like it extends below the image and is causing a little blue tic mark on the bottom right side. I've tried setting border to none and a few other css solutions but nothing seems to be working. I appreciate any help anyone can give. Here is a link to the test page. [Header_test](http://hornethq.lynchburg.edu/HQ_content_files/_header.php).

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code you have. Also, the question is slightly difficult to understand - explaining how you expect it to look would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options. First of which, the reason why you see the extra border is because the `a` tag is overflowing into the space between the images... so you can always just eliminate the spaces like so:

```
<a href="http://hornethq.lynchburg.edu/"><img class="announcement" src="../resources/images/headers/20150723announcement.png"></a>
<a href="http://hornethq.lynchburg.edu/"><img class="announcement" src="../resources/images/headers/20150723announcement.png"></a>
<a href="http://hornethq.lynchburg.edu/"><img class="announcement" src="../resources/images/headers/20150723announcement.png"></a>
```

Alternatively, change the `CSS` for your `a` tags to:

```
a { display: inline-block; }
```

or:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }
```

to remove the underline.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, remove the fixed width/height for the `a` and apply `text-decoration: none` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the a styles in `header.css` line 63 for these one:

```
a { display: inline-block; }
```